# Place the Index.html To Run

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey

I am beginning to study AngularJS with Spring MVC and I wanted when I entered the system in the case http: // localhost: 8080 / he entered a home page that is called index.html, walked snooping on the Internet, most could not succeed in time to call the page.

This is my controller that just created to call the page as in the examples I've seen too.

```
package br.com.escconsultoria.standard.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class IndexController {

      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getIndexPage() {
            return new ModelAndView("/index");
        }

}
```

Beauty of this fine examples simply doing: it returns `index`, worked over my could not for nothing there I saw talking about using Template: Thymeleaf only that I could not even now he does not think where's the page.

```
package br.com.escconsultoria.standard.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.escconsultoria.standard.configuration",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.standard.controller",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.standard.repository",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.standard.service",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.imobiliario.controller",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.imobiliario.repository",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.imobiliario.service"})
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    /*@Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }*/

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000l);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/templates/**").addResourceLocations("/templates/");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to implement it?
My index page is in the `scr/main/resources/templates/index.html`

Solution:

Good I managed to solve my problem and I am putting the solution here, first the first thing that kept me from work was the Controller noted with RestController and needed to be only Controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "index3";
    }
}
```

And according to my App Configuration it looked like this.

```
package br.com.escconsultoria.standard.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.escconsultoria.standard.configuration",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.standard.controller",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.standard.repository",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.standard.service",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.imobiliario.controller",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.imobiliario.repository",
                               "br.com.escconsultoria.imobiliario.service"})
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000l);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/templates/**").addResourceLocations("/templates/");
    }
}
```

Then I had a little problem in the index that I was trying to do more was because they were generating in Pingendo and he did not close the tag in the case of the target, input and some other was not close at hand and it worked. My Test HTML below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<link
    href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>Brand</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label">Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                                    placeholder="Email"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3"
                                    placeholder="Password"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me </input></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there à train you are using EnableWebMvc ? This disable many things Spring boot would do automatically do for you

Comment: `2016-09-11 19:09:27.994  INFO 153040 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-09-11 19:09:28.050  INFO 153040 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]`

Comment: In the log appears to me these two lines would be a mistake?

Comment: I managed to solve the error not think I think, but now he's giving Parse error.

Comment: 2016-09-11 19:36:00.733 ERROR 291304 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler  : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-5] Fatal error during parsing

Comment: The type of target element "must be terminated by the matching end tag" </ meta> ".

Comment: 2016-09-11 19:36:00.734 ERROR 291304 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-5] Exception processing template "index": Exception parsing document: template="index", line 105 - column 3

Comment: These are the mistakes you are making.

Comment: This is so confusing.. sorry, I don't think I'll be able to help, I don't understand what is going when reading your post AND comments.

Comment: Thank you but I could solve. My communication is bad because not only born English, sorry. I will add the above solution.

Comment: Great! No worries! Glad you got your answer.